# Using \toptitlemarks and \bottitlemarks with any counters

Tags: header-footer, titlesec

`\toptitlemarks` and `\bottitlemarks` don't seem to work with random counters:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,pagesize=pdftex]{scrbook}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{mycounter}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
  \setheadrule{.009pt}
  \sethead[\thepage][]
    [\toptitlemarks\themycounter---%
      \bottitlemarks\themycounter]%
    {\toptitlemarks\themycounter---%
      \bottitlemarks\themycounter}{}{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\begin{document}

\stepcounter{mycounter}
\markboth{\themycounter}{\themycounter}
\Huge\themycounter

\lipsum[2]

\stepcounter{mycounter}
\markboth{\themycounter}{\themycounter}
\Huge\themycounter

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: toptitlemarks]

Is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I've adapted the code and the result in the question. It seems to work better, but now it gives funny results… (112­—22)

Comment: oh I just deleted my comment because I noticed the you _had_ used marks didn't notice you had edited the question:-) I'll run the code this time and see :-)

Comment: Sorry, I added your suggestion to my question instead of adding an edit to it, since it would have made the question longer and it still fails this way ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `titleps` package offers its own mechanism for handling new marks. You can use the `extramarks` mechanism described in the [`titleps`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titleps) package documentation (Section **6. Extra marks**):

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,pagesize=pdftex,twoside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[extramarks]{titleps}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\newmarkset{mycounter}
\newextramark*{mycounter}{mycounter}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{
  \setheadrule{.009pt}
  \sethead[pg(\thepage)][]
    [(\topextramarks{mycounter}{\arabic{mycounter}}---%
      \botextramarks{mycounter}{\arabic{mycounter}})]%
    {(\topextramarks{mycounter}{\arabic{mycounter}}---%
      \botextramarks{mycounter}{\arabic{mycounter}})}{}{pg(\thepage)}
}
\pagestyle{mystyle}

\newcommand\updatemark{%
\stepcounter{mycounter}%
\extramark{mycounter}%
}
\begin{document}

\updatemark
\Huge\themycounter

\lipsum[2]

\updatemark
\Huge\themycounter

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yeh +1 for having read some documentation:-) Actually this is clearly the right answer, I've deleted mine.

Comment: That works fine, thanks. Any way of doing this with `titlesec` maybe?

Comment: Nevermind, I got my answer. `titlesec` can be used together with it, so long as `pagestyle` is not used.